# Use ResolutionContext in tests for Automapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, automapper-12

How do I test an Automapper ITypeConverter Converter with a `ResolutionContext`?

I have a complicated converter and want to test it explicitly.
It needs an argument `ResolutionContext` which I cannot get to, nor create nor mock.
Is it possible?

```
public class MyConverter : ITypeConverter<SourceType, TargetType>
{
    public TargetType Convert(SourceType source, TargetType destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
       ...complicated code...
    }
}
```

---

**Edit/Clarification**: I am trying to *not* call `myMapper.Map(...` but these only the ´MyConverter.Convert` function.
I know it can be considered the wrong-way-to-test as one should only test public methods and this class/method is only public due to technical reasons and should really be private from OO point of view. But that discussion is for another forum.

Comment: You don't write tests for AutoMapper components. That's the job of AutoMapper itself. Just create a mapper from your configuration, create a source object with some specific values, map on the desired destination object and check the properties of the destination instance for correctness. That's it.

Comment: Are you needing/using the context in your converter? If so you probably can't test the Convert method directly. And I agree that TDD principles enforce that every method be testable. It's bad behavior for a modern framework to not allow mocking of framework components.

In my case, I wasn't using context, so I changed my method signature to have a nullable ResolutionContext?. The framework will always pass a context, but I can pass null in my test cases.

Answer (score 2):

The [source code](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/TypeConverters.cs) of the `TypeConverter` unit tests of AutoMapper itself show that they follow the regular flow:

- Set up a `MapperConfiguration`.
- Create a `Mapper` from it.
- Call one of the `Map` overloads.

By doing so AutoMapper takes care of passing a `ResolutionContext` to the `Convert` method.

Below code shows how the `Convert` method receives a `ResolutionContext` with a preconfigured `Items` dictionary.

```cs
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(
    o => o.CreateMap<SourceType, TargetType>().ConvertUsing<MyConverter>()
    // More mappings go here.
    );

var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

var source = new SourceType 
{
    Name = "foo" 
};

var target = mapper.Map<TargetType>(
    source,
    o =>
    {
        o.Items["foo"] = "bar";
    });

Console.WriteLine(target.Name); // bar
```

```cs
public class SourceType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TargetType
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyConverter : ITypeConverter<SourceType, TargetType>
{
    public TargetType Convert(SourceType source, TargetType destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // Complicated code goes here.
    
        return new TargetType
        {
            Name = (string)context.Items[source.Name]
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: That solution is how I solved the problem, to call `mapper.Map...`. My question was about how to not test the mapper but only the very `MyConverter.Concert`method. Thx anyway. I have updated the question.

Comment: As long as [ResolutionContext](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/104a192407858fe3a54a8a937ca95a34fd7c6959/src/AutoMapper/ResolutionContext.cs#L12) has a non public constructor or abstraction, there isn't much other to try when a converter relies on that `ResultionContext`.

Comment: I also believe in @pfx and @Oscar 's answer and comment. The "correct" solution is probably to test the very `mapper.Map`. If the tests get hard to read - create helper functions to create in data in a readable way.

Comment: I cannot mark you answer as the Answer though - as it doesn't Answer the Question. An upvote is all.

Comment: @LosManos, That is totally fine. I'm also open/curious for an other/better approach.

Answer (score 2):

In case your custom converter has any dependencies, this can be a possible workaround:

As per Automapper, ResolutionContext has no public constructor so mocking this is not possible, neither instantiating. We'll have to use an actual Mapper in order to test the custom converters with dependencies.

Here is the sample code for this, hope this helps:

```
public class MyConverterTests
{
    #region Private Variables
    private static readonly MyCustomConverter _myCustomConverter;
    private static readonly Mock<DependencyA> _dependencyA;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    #endregion

    static MyConverterTests()
    {
        _dependencyA = new Mock<DependencyA>();
        _myCustomConverter = new MyCustomConverter(_dependencyA.Object);
    }

    public MyConverterTests()
    {
        var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<CustomMapperProfile>());
        _mapper = new AutoMapper.Mapper(mapperConfiguration);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestCaseA()
    {
        // Do Testing
    }

    public class CustomMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public CustomMapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                .ConvertUsing(_myCustomConverter);
        }
    }
}

public class MyCustomConverter : ITypeConverter<Source, Destination>
{
    public MyCustomConverter(DependencyA dependency)
    {

    }

    public Destination Convert(Source source, Destination destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class DependencyA
{

}

public class Destination
{

}

public class Source
{

}
```